# How to properly reverse an order of a row in MSSQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I do have this MSSQL stored procedure, that creates a `table` using a `csvString` and reverse the order of the rows of it. But in my case It did not reverse the order of my rows. Below is my stored procedure, with comments included such as the incorrect results and results I want.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MY_STOREDPROC]
 @csv_string NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @separator NCHAR(1)= '#'
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare a table variable to hold the csv rows
    DECLARE @csv_table TABLE (row NVARCHAR(MAX))

     --Split the csv string into rows and insert them into the table variable
    INSERT INTO @csv_table
    SELECT value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@csv_string, @separator)
    WHERE LEN(value) > 0

    -- Print the rows in the table variable
    SELECT * FROM @csv_table

--RESULT:
--       row
-----------------------
--Mark,Fernandez,Rodriguez,Male,25
--Anne,Poe,Rodriguez,Male,30
--Zed,Smith,Garcia,Female,17
--Miya,Marksman,Gold,Female,25


    -- Print the rows returned by the stored procedure in reversed order(supposedly but it does not)
     SELECT row 
    FROM (
        SELECT row, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY row DESC) AS row_number
        FROM @csv_table
    ) AS t
    ORDER BY row DESC

--  RESULT:
--      row
-----------------------
--Zed,Smith,Garcia,Female,17
--Miya,Marksman,Gold,Female,25                                              
--Mark,Fernandez,Rodriguez,Male,25                                                                
--Anne,Poe,Rodriguez,Male,30


--RESULT I WANT 
--row
-----------------------
--Miya,Marksman,Gold,Female,25
--Zed,Smith,Garcia,Female,17
--Anne,Poe,Rodriguez,Male,30
--Mark,Fernandez,Rodriguez,Male,25

END
```

Comment: Rows in a database table are not sorted. Your first `select` statement returns the rows in an arbitrary order, since it doesn't have an `order by` clause. For more information, read  my blog post entitled [The “Natural order” misconception](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/)

Comment: Your results appear to be ordered alphabetically in reverse order as I would expect. Your desired results are ordered `M>Z>A>M`.... how is the "reverse" of ordering them alphabetically? This not even an "order"

Comment: So should I include some sort of keys when creating the table?

Comment: Whatever you need to order on needs to be a column in the table, key or not.

Comment: Well if you want to control the ordering, and ordering by the column value is not what you want, then yes you'll need *something* that defines your correct order.

Comment: @Stu I am ordering them from bottom to top

Comment: There is no first, last, top, or bottom in an unordered set (table).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want the values in the reverse order that they appear in `@csv_string`, although since you've not included the starting value for this, that is a bit of a guess.

If I have guessed correctly, then in SQL Server 2022, Azure SQL Database, and Azure SQL Managed Instance you can specify that you want the ordinal when using string split, and retain the original position in the string, so you can get your desired result with something like this:

```
DECLARE @csv_string NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Mark,Fernandez,Rodriguez,Male,25#Anne,Poe,Rodriguez,Male,30#Zed,Smith,Garcia,Female,17#Miya,Marksman,Gold,Female,25',
    @separator NCHAR(1)= '#'

DECLARE @csv_table TABLE (Position INT, row NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT @csv_table(Position, row)
SELECT  ss.ordinal, ss.value
FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@csv_string, @separator, 1) AS ss

SELECT  ct.row
FROM    @csv_table AS ct
ORDER BY ct.Position;

SELECT ct.row
FROM @csv_table AS ct
ORDER BY ct.Position DESC;
```

In versions that don't support `ordinal` then you can (ab)use `OPEN_JSON` to split your string, which gives you the ordinal in the `key` column:

```
DECLARE @csv_string NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Mark,Fernandez,Rodriguez,Male,25#Anne,Poe,Rodriguez,Male,30#Zed,Smith,Garcia,Female,17#Miya,Marksman,Gold,Female,25',
    @separator NCHAR(1)= '#'

DECLARE @csv_table TABLE (Position INT, row NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT @csv_table(Position, row)
SELECT  oj.[Key], oj.Value
FROM    OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(@csv_string, @separator, '","'), '"]')) AS oj;

SELECT  ct.row
FROM    @csv_table AS ct
ORDER BY ct.Position;

SELECT ct.row
FROM @csv_table AS ct
ORDER BY ct.Position DESC;
```

**[Examples on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8KCHElrk)**

Comment: The optional ordinal for `STRING_SPLIT` is not available in SQL 2019; it was introduced in Azure SQL Database and is available in Azure SQL MI, and SQL 2022 too.

Comment: @DanGuzman Cheers, I tend to think of Azure database as comparable with SQL Server 2019 simply because they are both have 150 as the default compatibility level, but appreciate that it my not be the correct terminology for this. I will update the answer

Comment: Can you put an output parameter to the second stored procedure you suggested @GarethD? wherein I can put the reversed csv

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I follow what you want here. Do you want to create a new string that reverses the original one and return a single string from the stored procedure?

Comment: In MSSQL, we can put an output parameter like this `@reversedCsv NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT,` in order for us to return the reversed CSV

Comment: You should be able to use [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to rebuild your string, you can use the `WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ....)` to ensure the new string has the order you want. If your sole purpose is to return a string I'd be inclined to use a function over a procedure though, e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/dMeZtfax

Comment: @Nick, here's the [STRING_AGG reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql).